# Existence of Annihilating Polynomial for a Linear Operator over a fine dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

How do I show the existence of Annihilating Polynomial for a Linear Operator $T:V\to V$ over a finite dimensional vector space $V$.

I had an idea that $\mathbb{L}(V,V)$ is a vector space of dimension $n^2$.
Hence considering the set $I,T,T^2,T^3, \dots \dots T^{n^2}$ which has $n^2+1$ elements, must be dependent.
Hence we got the annihilating polynomial.

But my Professor wasn't happy, He said that some set had dimension $n$ and considering the set $I,T,T^2,T^3, \dots \dots T^n$ which has $n+1$ elements.

This gives us two cases.

case $1$
If All $T^i$ are distinct, we get a dependent set, hence we can conclude.
Otherwise

case $2$
 we must have $T^i=T^j$ for some $0\leq i<j\leq n$
Hence it is also dependent.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you discussed the "Cayley-Hamilton theorem" in this class?

Comment: the proof you gave is certainly the simplest, most elementary one. If you want a polynomial of degree $n$, then one possibility is to resort to the Cayley Hamilton theorem, since the characteristic polynomial certainly annihilates $T$

Comment: It sounds like your professor was talking about [cyclic subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace)

Comment: If you haven't discussed Cayley-Hamitlon, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258260/81360) should be helpful

Comment: No, we haven't not done cavley-hamilton theorem yet, Its just the begining. He was actually trying to prove that the mapping $\sigma:R\[x\] \to L\mathbb{T}(V)$ defined by $ \sigma(p(x))=p(T)$ has nontrivial kernel.