# Properties of the polynomials of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For a complex square matrix $M$, let us say $n\times n$, we can define the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism,

$$ \phi_M:\mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow Y_M:=\{N\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})|[M,N]=0\}$$
$$p(x)\mapsto p(M)$$

I would like to know when it is surjective (onto $Y_M$), I already know that for a diagonalizable matrix $M$ it is the case iff $M$ has distinct eigenvalues, but for the case where $M$ has a nilpotent part I do not know any conditions.

Comment: $P(M)$ always commute with $M$. I did not understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be shown using the [Cayley Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) or [other means](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258260/81360), the image of this homomorphism is a subspace of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ with dimension at most equal to $n$. So to answer your question, this homomorphism is never surjective except in the trivial cases of $n=0,1$.

For a given $M \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$, the image of this homomorphism attains its largest possible value of $n$ if and only if $M$ [is a non-derogatory matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787808/81360). As is noted in this linked answer, this is also equivalent to the image of the homomorphism being the entire set of matrices that commute with $M$.

Comment: I guess he means surjective in the subspace of matrices that commute with $M$ and not in $\Bbb C^{n\times n}$

Comment: @InsideOut That's an interesting guess, I hope we get some clarification

Comment: PS: my mistake I wrote “he” in place of OP. I’m sorry!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, surgective onto the matrices that commute with $M$.

Comment: @A Thanks for clarifying. In any case, you have your answer: it is surjective if and only if $M$ is non-derogatory.

Comment: The post really solves my problem, but it is not clear (for me) the last equivalence, could I get some reference please?

Comment: “Matrix Analysis” by Horn and Johnson 2nd edition has a proof of this in chapter 3